# Java spring what is the point of XML programming?

Tags: java, xml, spring

I'm going through the Spring right now and have some things on my mind. What is the point of doing so many things in the XML files? I've been through searching for the answer for this but found nothing interesting. I mean all those denpendency injections and declaring objects present way much better when written in Java, don't they? XML is not intuitive and there's aparently more code to write and I'm in the very beginning of my Spring path but I don't feel like this can be useful in the future... Can somebody explain to me what is so good about bringing programming to the XML? Or maybe pass me the link of some article which may help me? Thanks!

Comment: I won't post this as an answer per se, since I'm not sure this question can be answered definitively. But two things: 1. Spring has been moving toward providing more non-XML configuration options (with annotations-based configuration and Java config using `@Configuration` files). 2. As a declarative language, XML *should* be the best tool for the declarative work of explaining how objects depend on one another. In practice, I agree that isn't really the case. But the theory is that you should use the weakest tool capable of solving the problem.

Answer (score 2):

This is a complaint that comes from everyone who starts in Spring. It was way worse back in the 1.0 days. I have been doing XML configs in Spring and Struts for many years and have converted most if not all of my code to the new Spring annotated @Configuration and Springboot.

1) If you are new to Spring use Spring STS(Eclipse as your IDE) http://spring.io/tools ->Spring tool Suite.

2) Springboot - Remember that the whole idea behind Springboot is to get rid of all of what you are complaining about. Nearly all the configuration is done without XML.

3) Maven - The only real file you will need in XML is the POM.xml for your dependencies but Spring STS has a wrapper interface that will help you add dependencies as you go.

4) Pivital TC- When you start Spring STS you will notice it comes with Pivital's version of Tomcat.

5)  File -> New-> Spring Starter Project: Select Web and Thymleaf(JSP replacement) I have lost my desire to code in JSP.

You will notice the DemoApplication.java class

```js
package demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Notice that everything is now done without XML. The ApplicationContext.XM is now a simple Java class.

Springboot has a bunch of great new annotations that will take all the XML way :)

If there is something specific you want to do just add it in the comments below and I can guide you further. Thymeleaf is pretty simple you just add your HTML files in the /demo/src/main/resources/templates directory.

Good luck! Don't give up Spring is very powerful.

Answer (score 0):

You have to look at the history behind the introduction of the Spring Framework as a better programming model than EJB2.x at the time it was introduced to understand where it is today. However, EE5, 6 and 7 have now changed radically to improve developer productivity, more convention over configuration, and use of annotations to indicate behavior of POJO classes.

Although Spring has been moving away from XML based configuration for a while and also using more annotations, you have to ask yourself at this point whether you'd rather Spring's implementation of JSR250 (Common Annotations) and JSR330 (Dependency Injection), or EE6 and 7, since both implement the same specs. There will probably be many heated replies to this point of view, but you have to take a good look at what it is you're trying to do before deciding on one verses the other. If you're planning on deploying a Spring based app to an EE6+ app server, then a pure EE solution might be the simplest and easiest approach.

Answer (score -1):

I think ideally you wouldn't be programming in XML. In the end, it's not a programming language but a markup language.
I guess people use it because a markup language can be read and understood even by a person without a technical background, and also because processing an XML file is cheaper than calling the Java engine and using that in applications.